# SQL Trigger in VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a VB.NET Simple application that creates a database and creates tables in SQL Server. I want to be able to create an SQL Trigger in SQL Server from VB.NET. ie. create trigger statement in vb.net. I know how to create it in code with SQL Management Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can run sql code in SqlCommand in vb

```
Dim sqlConnection1 As New SqlConnection("Your Connection String")
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TRIGGER trig_Update_Employee etc etc etc"
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1

sqlConnection1.Open()

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

sqlConnection1.Close()
```

Comment: Any example will be very helpful?

Comment: I was on the right path except trigger was multiple lines and when terminated, had the next line keyword combine with the previous line without space. eg.  strTrigger = "CREATE TRIGGER LastLogin ON [dbo].[Users]" & _
"FOR UPDATE " & _
"AS " & _
"SET NOCOUNT ON " &  etc. Note the space after "FOR UPDATE " , "AS "instead of "FOR UPDATE", "AS". Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to create a SQL stored procedure that is passed the name of the trigger by VB.

When you pass SQL commands with CommandText, you run the risk of SQL injection attacks.